# animated loads in wrong spot

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a div that animates up and down which works fine. The issue I'm getting is that every time the page loads the div starts at the very top of the page and then jumps down to where it needs to be after the animation starts.

```
<body id="body">
  <div id="square"></div>
</body>


#body {
  background: #000;
}

#square {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  }

var box = document.getElementById('square');
TOP = (window.innerHeight - box.offsetHeight)/2;
box.style.top = TOP;

var down = setInterval(animateDown, 15);
    var up;

    function animateDown()
    {
        TOP += 3;
        box.style.top = TOP + 'px';
        if(TOP > 900){
            clearInterval(down);
            up = setInterval(animateUp, 15);
        }

    }

    function animateUp()
    {
        TOP -= 3;
        box.style.top = TOP + 'px';
        if(TOP <= (window.innerHeight - box.offsetHeight)/2){
            clearInterval(up);
            down = setInterval(animateDown, 15);
        }

    }
```

Here is a link to the jsfiddle as well >> https://jsfiddle.net/xgilmore/pLbgvc3L/

thanks in advance

Comment: works fine for me(not in jsfiddle)

Comment: What browser were you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a work around, but you can start the box off as hidden, and then once you start animating, set it visible. https://jsfiddle.net/pLbgvc3L/1/

```
function animateDown()
    {
    box.style.visibility = 'visible';

#square {
  background-color: #fff;
  //margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 20%;
  visibility: hidden;
  }
```

Oh sorry, I actually know what is going on, it just took a second look to figure it out. `top: 20%` doesn't do anything because percentages only work if the parent element (body) has an explicit height. Like so https://jsfiddle.net/pLbgvc3L/2/

Comment: Though I'd still like to figure out whats going on, this does get the job done.